# Custom UIview with UIBezierPath like ice cream cone

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath, swift4.2

I am making a location marker that is dynamic imageView inside it and the background has gradient color

I tried to make Circle with `UIbezierpath` and thought of adding the traingle view to it but all failed

[image]

I am trying to achieve this the image is not static

Answer (score 0):

use paint code or UIbezierpath or simply use image